# "Destination Host Unreachable" on ping

Tags: networking

After network-manager could not connect to my router which has IP 192.168.1.1.

I set static ip for my interface. It connects but I cannot ping. I get "Destination host unreachable" whenever I ping from this particualar pc. I can ping and connect fine with same interface and router with my laptops when wired though.

I have set interface ip as:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

How can I make my pc connect with internet? Please Help

EDIT:
ifconfig
[image: ifconfig]

ip route
[image: ip route]

ethtool
[image: ethtool]

traceroute
[image: traceroute]

The mii-tool one said unsupported.

Comment: what's the output of `ifconfig` when you type it into a terminal? Which adapter is wireless and which is wired? eth0 is normally wired.

Comment: its wired and its an old desktop pc with external NIC. ifconfig shows me interface with all the ips I set.

Comment: So you only have eth0? There are no other interfaces or ports? If so, and if your other machines can access the router, it may be a hardware problem.

Comment: yes and It used to connect fine until yesterday

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem then. Have you checked that ethernet cable recently? Maybe a chair rolled over it in the last day or so. Does the cable work with your laptop? Are you using the same port on your router each time?

Comment: yes the cable works with my laptop.

Comment: Update your post with the output of: `sudo nm-tool`

Comment: isn't nm-tool part of networkmanager? I have set static ip and purged network manager.

Comment: Post the output of `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ping 192.168.1.1` pls.

Comment: @karthick87: resolv.conf is used for DNS, it has nothing to do with this issue. @sagarchalise: Either the router does not work, or you're missing a route. Can you add he output of `ip route show` to your answer?

Comment: updated and basically resolv.conf would have nameserver which in my case is 192.168.1.1

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. I assume that when you say 'connects' you mean link-up on the interface ports of your PC and router.
   However, I don't understand why that should happen only after you use static-IP -- maybe your interface was configured down initially.
2. If your router IP is 192.168.1.1 it is very likely to be a Class-B subnet configuration.
   This means the netmask would be `255.255.0.0`.
   By using a Class-C netmask and a network number of `192.168.1.0`,
   you have placed your PC in a different subnet from your router.
   That would explain the ping unreachable case.

So, I think you should try with,

```
iface eth0 inet static  
    address 192.168.1.2  
    netmask 255.255.0.0  
    network 192.168.0.0  
    broadcast 192.168.255.255  
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

You can check the physical connectivity with `mii-tool`.
It is part of the `net-tools` package.

Comment: Why should it be Class-b?

Comment: No, the 192 block is a bank of class C addresses and your home router uses a netmask of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: For many networks, you can't assume any prefix length based on the IP address any more.  This is an assumption network equipment and stacks made before classless networks were common.  I think most home routers would set 192.168.x.x as a Class C, though, based on legacy pre-CIDR stuff.